# Строки настраиваемых числовых форматов

Tags: форматирование, java, blackberry

Нужен такой метод:

На входе - число типа `double` и строка, содержащая правила форматирования;
эти правила соответствуют (не обязательно строго полностью) вот этому стандарту: [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

На выходе - строка, содержащая отформатированное по этим правилам число.

Есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека для Java, которая такое делает?

P.S.:

В конечном счёте это будет запускаться на `BlackBerry`. К сожалению, `Java API` там очень сильно урезанный, - подобной стандартной библиотеки для форматирования там нет.

Comment: Этот мелкомягкий формат чисел обязателен  или требуется просто форматирование чисел по пользовательскому шаблону? String.format на Blackberry нет?

Comment: напишите что-то свое. если String.format метод, *Formatter классы вырезаны то можете взять их исходный код, врапнуть отверткой которая парсила б входной формат и приводила к их формату

Comment: Не обязательно полное соответствие мелкомягкому формату. Требуется просто форматирование чисел по пользовательскому шаблону.

Я сначала захотел взять из исходников cтандартного Java API класс java.text.DecimalFormat, но в результате пришлось бы ещё десятки классов тянуть. Это ещё терпимо, но кроме этого ещё и исходник одного из классов из пакетов sun.* просто не нашёлся.

Answer (score 1):

[На SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094700/j2me-number-format) товарищ портировал `DecimalFormat` на J2ME и закачал на [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/bbnumberformat/source/checkout).